# C# extensions and Linq in Pythonnet

Tags: c#, python-3.x, python.net

I have a class `ObjectExtensions` which stores all written by me C# extensions. Currently, if I have (in Python with the use of `pythonnet`) an object `object` of class `MyClass` then to use extension I need to write `ObjectExtensions.MyExtension(object)`. Is it possible to use this extension as `object.MyExtension()`? And similarly, is it possible to use `Linq` queries in `pythonnet`, i.e. `Where`, `Select`, `ForEach` etc?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you have a class containing extensions methods, but you can't use them as extensions.

If so, your class is probably not designed correctly. It should look like this:

```
public static class ObjectExtensions
{
    public static void Method(this MyClass variable)
    {
         // rest of code
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work in Python. I.e in C# I can write `var object = new MyClas()` and then `object.Method()`. In python `object.Method()` throws an error and I have to use `ObjectExtensions.Method(object)` instead.

Comment: Is your variable name "object"? If so, you should consider changing it. I'm not familiar with pythonnet but it seems like something problematic.